# Github API: Example for creating Pull Request from Forked Repository

Tags: github, github-api

Need help with forming parameters to the Github API. I have a repository say `p-repo` and another repository say `f-repo` forked from `p-repo`. Now I want to raise a Pull Request via Github v3 API but I don't know how to form the parameters. Can anyone help me build it?

What I am trying is given below

```
POST https://api.github.com/repos/someuser/p-repo/pulls
title: 'A New PR'
body: 'Dummy Body'
head: 'master'
base: 'f-repo-username:master'
```

The response that I am getting is,

```
422 Error - Validation Failed
Fork collab can't be granted by someone without permission
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong, need help!

Comment: It looks like you are having an authentication issue. You probably need to add to headers to your request:
"User-Agent": USERNAME
"Authorization": "token TOKEN_VALUE"

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I forgot to post here that the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It was failing because in the API url I didn't use github username of the parent repo owner.